# wsDualHttpBinding works on LAN but doesn't work on internet

Tags: wcf, lan

I have a wcf simple program that use wsDualHttpBinding. I put my server.exe on another computer (on my LAN network) and called a method via client. callback successfully called at client. Then I put my server.exe on my VPS server (on Internet) and run client.exe, client throws TimeoutException.
I use 9090 port for server listening. Also I turn off firewall on both side.

what's wrong?
please help, it's going me crazy.

EDIT:
**Do both server and client need valid IP address?**

Comment: Can you post the configs of server and client. also post the entire exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has solved!

In duplex connections, both client and server need valid ip address.
I changed connection way. I used netTcp.

anyway tnx everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Check your client's config . Try increasing the below settings:

```
<binding name="WSDualHttpBindingEndpoint" 
openTimeout="00:01:00"
receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
sendTimeout="00:01:00"
```

Verify that the Service Operation is being called & is returning in a timely fashion.
Have Service write to log when method is entered & exited.

Also verify port 9090 is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to publish http metadata with metadata endpoint in your server.exe and open webservice page on client machine in browser.

I also recommend you to use nettcpbinding instead of wsDualHttpBinding even over the Internet because it's more stable, persistent channel and AFAIK wsDualHttpBinding requires two ports for normal duplex conversation (see ClientBaseAddress in client binding). Tcp needs one though